# Track who visits my website from clicking on my fb link through the facebook app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, analytics

I would like to test different landing pages. However, I am not able to track people that come from FB through the ios & android app. I can only track these people that come from the FB desktop and mobile browser.

Does anyone have a method to see if the user that's visiting your website clicked on your link from the facebook ios & android app so I can then show them a different landing page?

Comment: Have you considered using a FB pixel?